# similarity measure

Tags: statistics, similarity

I have some question concern similarity measure and i need your help (Iam new in statistics)

suppose that we have a matrix M where M(i, j) is the similarity measure between user i and user j .

Question :
1- what similarity measure choose and why?

2- What is the maximum size of the matrix? What are its properties? How would you choose the store?

Thank you very much for your help
bests

Answer (score 2):

The matrix will be mxm (assuming you have m items) but you don't need to fill it entirely, since a similarity measure should ideally be symmetric (sim(a,b) = sim(b,a)).

As to choosing one, it depends entirely on what you store and what you plan to do with it. Assuming you are storing vectors of objects, some popular simple ones are [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) and [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). [This page](http://mines.humanoriented.com/classes/2010/fall/csci568/portfolio_exports/mvoget/similarity/similarity.html) has a bit more information on them (along with some other similarity measures). I would encourage you to search for books and research papers in the area that you are exploring and see what common similarity metrics are used by the community.